# MySQL Find and replace but keep part of replacement

Tags: mysql

Ok so I know how to do a find and replace in Mysql but i am trying to do a find and replace but keep part of the replacement, or rather wrap the searched string.

I need to wrap all youtube embed codes in a javascript function:

```
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ibppIFuWNlg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>
```

I need to replace with say:

```
<script>
InsertHtml('<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ibppIFuWNlg" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media" allowfullscreen></iframe>', 'videoEmbed', null, null, 4);
</script>
```

Now using replace in mysql wouldnt work as there will be multiple iframes (youtube embeds) which all have a different video code.

Comment: In newest MySQL version you have REGEX_REPLACE() function, but you don't even need that. You can replace `<iframe ` and `</iframe>`.

Comment: took me a while to get you but of course i can! thanks man